# How do you add an attribute to your CSS selector to specify specific pagination link?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I just got into Scrapy & I’m aware this is a Noob question but How do I add an attribute to specify specific pagination link?

here is the html with the element I’m targeting.

```
`<div class="pagination">
<a rel="prev" href="/collections/all?page=1" class="fa fa-chevron-left prev pagination-icon"></a>
<ul>
                <li class="pagination-icon">
            <a href="/collections/all?page=1" title="">1</a>
            </li>
                <li class="pagination-icon pagination-icon--current">
            2
            </li>
                <li class="pagination-icon">
            <a href="/collections/all?page=3" title="">3</a>
            </li>
                <li class="pagination-icon">
            <a href="/collections/all?page=4" title="">4</a>
            </li>
                <li class="pagination-icon pagination-icon--current">
            …
            </li>
                <li class="pagination-icon">
            <a href="/collections/all?page=50" title="">50</a>
            </li>
</ul>
```

I Need to follow the link in this line

```
<a rel="next" href="/collections/all?page=3" class="fa fa-chevron-right next pagination-icon"></a>
```

Here is my scrapy code

```
            next_page = response.css('div.pagination a::attr(href)').extract_first()
    if next_page is not None:
        yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

What’s happening is its following this link instead of the other one because it is the first one in the class “pagination”

```
 <a rel="prev" href="/collections/all?page=1" class="fa fa-chevron-left prev pagination-icon"></a>
```

I can see 2 differences between the attributes of the 2 links, both in the class “pagination”

1. Rel attribute is different, I need the one with “next”
2. Class attribute is different, I need “fa fa-chevron-right next pagination-icon”

I’m pretty sure I can get the correct link by specifying one of the 2 attributes listed above in my css selector. I tried using the following CSS selectors but none worked.

1. div.pagination a.fa fa-chevron-right next pagination-icon a::attr(href) does not work
2. a.fa fa-chevron-right next pagination-icon a::attr(href) does not work
3. a.fa fa-chevron-right next pagination-icon::attr(href) does not work

How can I achieve my goal? Why do none of the CSS selectors I tried work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't select multiple classes with a single dot. Either combine each of them with dots or go for this syntax `"[class='fa fa-chevron-right next pagination-icon']"`. However, if any class out of them is generated dynamically then the selector will break.

Then try with this to see what happens.

```
response.css('div.pagination a[rel="next"]::attr(href)').extract_first()
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly,  had to remove the double quotes encasing next. response.css('div.pagination a[rel=next]::attr(href)').extract_first()